# Gulp: Limit file processing concurrency; avoid processing *all files* at the same time

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a **big** list of images (2874) that need to be optimized with `gulp-imagemin` but the OS apparently limits the number of open files. I can change that with [`ulimit`](http://www.maxlibin.com/gulp-spawn-emfile-error/) but it doesn't feel particularly portable nor safe, given the file count.

This is my current code:

```
function optimizeImages() {
    return gulp.src('images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```

Is there a way to run a plugin on a subset of files at once? Like this

```
function exampleTask() {
    return gulp.src('images/*')
        .pipe(limitConcurrency(imagemin(), 50))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that [Gulp was updated](https://twitter.com/contrahacks/status/482326482359177217) to fix the error `Error: EMFILE, too many open files` recently but I hadn't updated yet. Now the concurrency issue is automatically solved!

I just ran this in my project folder:

```
npm update gulp
```

Comment: Good to know. One caveat: it's not totally solved: if you shell out to run Phantom.js or such-like you can still hit the limit and may need to implement a queue'd approach around such commands.